# Cannot seem to be able to play Minecraft 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open up Minecraft launcher (PC), it reads that I am playing on the latest release (1.13.2). However I see multiple questions on Arqade about Minecraft 1.14. Even with "Enable SnapShots" and "Historical Versions" enabled, I cannot see a "1.14" Version.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: May I know why this is downvoted? I honestly hate it when people downvote, without any reason or without stating why they did so. Please state why you did so.

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/why-dont-we-require-users-to-comment-their-reasons-for-down-voting

Comment: @Frank You still haven't stated why this question is downvoted.

Comment: And no one has to.

Comment: @Frank So your telling me you can downvote any question you want for no apparent reason?

Comment: Generally, you should downvote because you believe the post doesn't meet your quality standards, but no matter how you vote, you don't have to justify it.  Not to the poster, not to others, not to anyone.

Comment: It was probably downvoted because the answer is extremely easy: Click the arrow next to the play button and select "latest snapshot". Every tutorial on how to install snapshot should have told you that. And even if not, trying a few buttons usually helps. (Remark: I was not the downvoter.)

Comment: It's irritating that people often don't provide a reason for downvotes, but it happens all over and isn't a requirement. Just be a good soul yourself and provide comments when voting. I always do.

Comment: @FabianRöling I has no clue about the snapshot being 1.14. I saw a snapshot "19w05a", but i was uncertain if that was  what people called 1.14. It also shows that 1.13.2 is the latest thing released, even with snapshots on. This thing has been clarified inside an answer that I have accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The development versions of the Java Edition are called "snapshots", and have a versioning format like "19w05a", which states the year (19), week number (05) and weekly identifier (a). In the example case (19w05a), the snapshot is first (a) snapshot of week 05 in 2019.

So, to play Java Edition 1.14 development versions, you need to first enable snapshots from the launcher settings and play profile "Latest Snapshot".

Comment: And to add, an official 1.14 isn't out yet. The snapshots are more of a preview or work-in-progress of 1.14 (or whatever preceding version).

Comment: Ahh. I saw a 19w05a, but i was confused to what it meant.